# Scaffold for ActionController::API in a regular Rails 5 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For projects generated with --app, an API-only controller can be created f.e. with:

```
bin/rails g scaffold Supplier name:string
```

The exact same code can be used in a regular Rails 5 project to provide a simple API-only resource, only changing the controller base class to ActionController::API.

Is there a way to generate/scaffold the exact same code in a regular Rails project?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is:

- Disable the jbuilder gem in the Gemfile
- Temporarily [configure the app as api_only in application.rb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#changing-an-existing-application)
- The scaffold will be generated as in an --app project then
- Change the controller base class to 'ActionController::API' manually